# Android global scope String returns null

Tags: android, string

I have a String declared at a class level.

```
String eta;
```

I am passing a url to a method in that same class that will use volley to retrieve distance from one of Google apis. I then assign the response String to my global variable eta. It has the needed value within the method but the global value is null when it is returned. I can't understand this behavior. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public String getDuration(String url){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    String  j = response.getString("rows");
                    JSONArray rowa = new JSONArray(j);
                    JSONObject rowobj = rowa.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray elementsa = rowobj.getJSONArray("elements");
                    for (int i = 0; i < elementsa.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject currentObject = elementsa.getJSONObject(i);
                        String duration = currentObject.getString("duration_in_traffic");
                        JSONObject timeObject = new JSONObject(duration);
                        **eta = timeObject.getString("text"); //eta has the needed value**
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
        **return eta; //here eta is null**
    }
```

Comment: Your `JsonObjectRequest` runs asynchronously, so the `onResponse()` method will not have yet run before the `getDuration()` method returns.

Comment: @Mike M, it makes complete sense. How can I work around that?

Comment: Don't return anything from `getDuration()`. Instead, do whatever you need to do with `eta` at the end of the `onResponse()` method.

Comment: what is the usage of the `eta`? is it used to update a value of TextView or something?

Comment: The reason I am doing that is to call getDuration in onCreate() method and some other method at different times and retrieve the time. Looks like I have to change my design against Polymorphism. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onResponse(JSONObject response)` is asynchronous.

You are calling `getDuration(String url)` and setting a listener that will be called when the network operation ends.
Instead of waiting the listener to be called you are returning the value (that it is not set at the moment) and that's why you get a null value.

Inside `onResponse(JSONObject response)` you should call the method that needs eta value.

```
public void getDuration(String url){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String  j = response.getString("rows");
                JSONArray rowa = new JSONArray(j);
                JSONObject rowobj = rowa.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray elementsa = rowobj.getJSONArray("elements");
                for (int i = 0; i < elementsa.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = elementsa.getJSONObject(i);
                    String duration = currentObject.getString("duration_in_traffic");
                    JSONObject timeObject = new JSONObject(duration);
                    eta = timeObject.getString("text"); //eta has the needed value**
                    methodThatUsesValue(eta);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code in line with the asynchronous nature of the callback and polymorphism principles. I appreciate everyone who gave me and answer.